# Settings app crash after Samsung update

Tags: samsung, settings

Performed a software update today on my S22 Exynos (no root, stock firmware).
Update went smoothly, but now settings app won't open, instead crashing immediately.
Clearing cache partition did not fix it.
So I checked the logcat and I found this:

```
04-22 03:05:37.832 19859 19859 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-22 03:05:37.832 19859 19859 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 03:05:37.832 19859 19859 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.settings, PID: 19859
04-22 03:05:37.832 19859 19859 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.homepage.SettingsHomepageActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #59 in com.android.settings:layout/sec_settings_base_layout: Could not inflate Behavior subclass androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.Opacity
```

[Full error stack trace](https://pastebin.com/Zxiybvzy).

This error seems different than presented by other similar questions, which involved missing packages. Right now I have no idea what to do with this information, but if anyone can help me avoid a hard reset I'd be very grateful.

Comment: backup your apps with [D2D](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.easyMover), adb backup or google drive, *adb pull -a /sdcard* pictures to PC and do factory reset